# Exception Caused by Predicate with CONTAINS 

Tags: ios, exception, core-data

I am getting this weird exception and I have no clue how to figure out what's going wrong here

```
"Serious application error.  **Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.**  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  **Can't look for value (552284302) in string (1070635162, 630076961, 690758344, 714304224, 693603903, 650263092, 552284302); value is not a string  with userInfo (null)**"
```

My code is as follows:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

NSManagedObjectContext *context =   [ (MyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                               entityForName:@"MyEntityName" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] 
                          initWithKey:@"distance" ascending:YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

User *user = [[DatabaseHelper sharedInstance] getUserDetails];
NSString *predicteString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"isPrivate == %@  AND recepientList contains %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], user.userId];

if(dootType == UnReadDootType){
    predicteString = [predicteString stringByAppendingString:@" AND state = 'NEW' "];
}


NSPredicate *predicate;
if(senderId != nil && [senderId intValue] > 0){
    predicteString = [predicteString stringByAppendingString:@" AND senderId == %@"];

    predicate = [NSPredicate
                 predicateWithFormat:predicteString, senderId];

}else{
    predicate = [NSPredicate
                 predicateWithFormat:predicteString];
}

[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];


NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = 
[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
                                    managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil 
                                               cacheName:@"MyEntityName"];

self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

[sort release];
[fetchRequest release];
[theFetchedResultsController release];

return _fetchedResultsController;    

}
```

The NSFetchRequest logs as:

```
<NSFetchRequest: 0x362350> (entity: MyEntityName; predicate: (isPrivate == 1 AND recepientList CONTAINS 552284302); sortDescriptors: ((
    "(distance, ascending, compare:)"
)); batch size: 20; type: NSManagedObjectResultType; )
```

So as you can see I am using a predicate like `recepientList CONTAINS 552284302` 
and for one of my record the recepientList has `1070635162, 630076961, 690758344, 714304224, 693603903, 650263092, 552284302` I am storing comma separated userId in the recepientList, so I am not sure why this exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `user.userID` is being parsed as a numerical value instead of a string. The `CONTAINS` operator does not understand numerical values.

The predicate that logs as:

```
(isPrivate == 1 AND recepientList CONTAINS 552284302)
```

… should log as:

```
(isPrivate == 1 AND recepientList CONTAINS "552284302")
```

The former predicate looks for a numerical value while later looks for a string. (Note that the numerical one in `isPrivate == 1` is not quoted.)

If `user.userID` is a NSNumber then getting it's string value should correct the problem. Try:

```
NSString *predicteString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"isPrivate == %@  AND recepientList contains %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], [user.userId stringValue]];
```

Comment: Thanks TechZen for the quick response, user.userId is NSString only it is not an NSNumber, and i don't get this error everytime, some time i see this error and some time i don't.

Comment: Well, I can tell you that the predicate as logged is treating it as a number. Strings should be double or single quoted. You can test the predicate using an array of dictionaries with a `recpientList` key. You will get the same error as above. It's clearly a problem with the predicate parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @TechZen, his answer gave me a hint to figure out the right answer.

@TechZen you were absolutely correct that the predicate should log as

```
(isPrivate == 1 AND recepientList CONTAINS "552284302")
```

But the thing is user.userId is not a NSNumber it is a NSString, so the problem is with this line

```
NSString *predicteString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"isPrivate == %@  AND recepientList contains %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], user.userId];
```

I changed this to

```
 NSString *predicteString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"isPrivate == %@ ", [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];

 predicteString = [predicteString stringByAppendingString:@"AND recepientList contains %@"];
 predicate = [NSPredicate
                 predicateWithFormat:predicteString, user.fbUserId];
```

and that's it now I get it as expected. I don't know why NSString stringWithFormat is treating a NSString as a NSNumber, while NSPredicate treat it in a right way.